# Blank profile name in Eclipse, Websphere Settings

Tags: eclipse, websphere, websphere-7

I am trying to add a New Server (WebSphere Application Server 7) to Eclipse (Kelper).  I have just installed WebSphere Application Server 7 on the PC but have not changed any settings yet (default settings).

In Eclipse, after New Server -> WebSphere Application Server Settings it shows me the following:

[image]

As you can see the Profile name box is empty, with no choices in the drop down box.  When I  click Configure profiles... I see:

[image]

At this point I am stuck.  I'm guessing that I already have a profile setup in websphere, but that maybe it doesn't have write permissions yet?

What do I have to do to get this server working in Eclipse?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the second image looks like you dont have any profiles. Check if you have any profiles (folders) e.g. `AppSrv01` in the `C:\Program files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles`.

If you have - it means that you dont have write permissions to that folder - try to run Eclipse `as Administrator`. Did you installed WebSphere with your user or Administrator? In general as a best practice you should avoid installing WebSphere in Program Files.

If you don't have - create it using for example `Profile Management Tool` - should be available in your `Start` menu.

You probably don't have rights, because the `"Run Profile Management Tool"` button should be enabled, if you would highlight WebSphere Runtime in upper table.

Comment: Your second paragraph did the trick!  My user profile in windows 7 was missing write and was read only for the IBM folder.  For those experiencing the same problem, right click your windows folders (eclipse & IBM) and make sure you have Properties -> Security -> Username has write checked.  If not Edit...  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue.
If you install websphere in

> C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles

instead of:

> C:\Program files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles

Then it will solve lots of configuration problems related to access.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If your `C:\Program files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles` dir is empty go to:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21442487

Download the attached zip and extract it to WebSphere's bin directory and run the bat/sh.