# Eclipse Luna on Linux and WebSphere 8.5 - unable to add server

Tags: eclipse, websphere

I always get this error when I'm going to add IBM WebSphere Server instance under Eclipse Luna (with WAS Server 8.5 tools installed)

'The profile name must match one of the WebSphere Application Server profile names defined on the WebSphere Application Server runtime.'

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like you don't have server profile created or your user don't have system rights to access it. Maybe you only installed binaries, without creating profile. Do you have folder `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/ProfileName`? If you have then try from `bin` folder issue `./serverStart.sh server1` and see if server successfully starts.

Comment: yes I've tried, it starts well also through firststeps, I've also runned eclipse as root, but nothing changed

Comment: That profile directory must be writable, so maybe try to set a+rw on the WebSphere/AppServer directory and make sure your user can write to profile directory. It looks very similar to [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163642/blank-profile-name-in-eclipse-websphere-settings)

Answer (score 0):

After click configure profiles, then you should create a profile in the Profile Management Tool first, (if required, we can enable admin security by providing username and password and this logon information will be used when we login into WAS Admin Console for WAS Configuration), after that Profile Name will automatically show on that drop-down list.

Answer (score 0):

Go the place where the WebSphere is installed right click on the folder and go to security giv[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPXUS.png)e

Comment: Go the place where the WebSphere is installed right click on the folder and go to security give write permission to the user